# How to properly feed specific tensor to keras model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

To allow using Keras model as part of standard tensorflow operations, I create a model using specific placeholder for the input.

However, when trying to do model.predict, I get an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [100,84,84,4]
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[100,84,84,4], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

My code is given below:

```
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
from keras.losses import mean_absolute_error
from keras.activations import relu
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import gym

state_size = [100, 84, 84, 4]

input_tensor = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=state_size)

inputL = Input(tensor=input_tensor)
h1 = Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(4,4), activation=relu) (inputL)
h2 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation=relu) (h1)
h3 = Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=relu) (h2)
h4 = Dense(512, activation=relu) (h3)
out = Dense(18) (h4)

model = Model(inputL, out)

opt = Nadam()


disc_rate=0.99

sess = tf.Session()
dummy_input = np.ones(shape=state_size)

model.compile(opt, mean_absolute_error)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
writer.close()

print(out)

print(model.predict({input_tensor: dummy_input}))
```

I have also trying feeding the input directly(no dictionary, just the value) - same exception. I can, however, get the model to work like:

```
print(sess.run( model.output, {input_tensor: dummy_input }))
```

Is there a way for me to still use normal Keras .predict method?

Comment: You can think of a `keras.Input` instance as a placeholder (not necessarily a TensorFlow placeholder). Instead of providing it a pre-defined tensor, initialise it with `shape` and `dtype`, then you can use `model.predict(dummy_input)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works (we need to initialize global variables):

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # initialize 
print(sess.run([model.output], feed_dict={input_tensor: dummy_input}))
```